# Newbie using Ubuntu 21.04, Problem with ‘Metered Connection’

Tags: internet

See image. Updates paused but metered connection box unchecked. How to fix this?

The solution should be something a newbie can implement.

This thread is relevant https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-software/-/issues/996 but I was unable to follow all the posts that had lots of terminal commands. Is that the only way to fix this?

Can I get around this issue by just manually running 'sudo apt update' and 'sudo apt upgrade'? Will that upgrade the same group of apps?

Thx.
[image: Metered connection?]

Comment: Manual or not metered is metered.

Comment: Yea the guis just run the same commands behind the scenes.  Run `tail -f /var/log/ufw.log`. what do you see?

Comment: Sure. Here's what I got. I'm a newbie so I don't know what it means. The command stopped (hanged) so I killed it with ctrl-C. 

advait@advait-Bravo-15-A4DDR:~$ tail -f /var/log/ufw.log
Aug 30 11:51:33 advait-Bravo-15-A4DDR kernel: [ 8889.430927] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp4s0 OUT= MAC=50:2f:9b:aa:a1:b3:92:c7:af:10:36:13:08:00 

... etc etc....

^C
advait@advait-Bravo-15-A4DDR:~$

Comment: You can see the entire results of the command here. https://imgur.com/a/xVjVOe5 If you know what it means let me know. Thx.

Comment: All my internet is pre-paid so it's all "metered", but the price is very low so there's no reason for metering to be turned on.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved with command:

```
nmcli connection modify Galaxy\ A71BD53 connection.metered no
```

Comment: How did you get the number A71BD53? It would help other users, who might have a different number.

Comment: The SSID for my phone is "Galaxy A71BD53". This ssid has a space in it so I was told to use "\ " so that the Linux terminal would correctly recognize the space. A71BD53 has nothing to do with Linux or the command syntax. It's just part of the ssid for my phone. There's a special name for "\ " but I forget what it is. One of the experts here will know.

Comment: Ok, I get it. Thank you.